# How do I use d3.js to display text in an SVG rect only if the text will fit?

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, visualization

I am creating a visualization with d3 that contains a bunch of rect elements of different sizes.  I'd like to put in a "caption" into each rect element, but I'd only like it to be displayed if the text fits naturally.  How would this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You get the bounding box of the text, check whether it's too big for the `rect` element and remove it if this is the case. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929) is an example of how to get the bounding box of a text element.